# sharetribe - change market place from selling to rental type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, marketplace

I've setup sharetribe on my server : https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe
But by mistake during setup I set the market place to selling. But instead I need it to be of type : rental.

Is there a way to do so without installing the entire thing again ?
Any thoughts will help.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! The "Selling" type is just a template for settings that we use when you create a new marketplace. It will set you an Order Type with title "Selling". All the order type settings can be changed afterwards. Go to Admin > Order Types and create a new Order Type with title "Renting" and select pricing unit "day", and that's basically it.